# How to prevent execution of second query in spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have problem with JPA/Hibernate when fetching certain entity from database. Problem is that it executes two queries, even thou first one is sufficient to gather or data that I need for the entity.

The type of entity I am taling has self reference. Here it is:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "franchises")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "Franchise.Parent.Country",
        attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode("parent"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("country"),
        }
    ),
})
public class Franchise {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private FranchiseType type;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Franchise parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Country country;
}
```

And here is the repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface IFranchiseRepository extends JpaRepository<Franchise, Long>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<Franchise>,
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Franchise>,
    FranchiseRepositoryCustom
{
    @EntityGraph("Franchise.Parent.Country")
    Optional<Franchise> findWithParentAndCountryById(long id);
}
```

Now in the controller I have this code:

```java
@GetMapping("/api/franchises/{franchise}")
public FranchiseDTO getFranchise(@PathVariable("franchise") long franchiseId) {
     var f = franchiseRepository.findWithParentAndCountryById(franchiseId).get();
     return null; // Do not worry about this statement, I am yet to map ti to DTO
}
```

When I call this api endpoint, i can see in console log that it is executng two queries:

```
SELECT
    franchise0_.id AS id1_6_0_,
    franchise1_.id AS id1_6_1_,
    country2_.id AS id1_3_2_,
    franchise0_.country_id AS country_6_6_0_,
    franchise0_.created_at AS created_2_6_0_,
    franchise0_.name AS name3_6_0_,
    franchise0_.parent_id AS parent_i7_6_0_,
    franchise0_.type AS type4_6_0_,
    franchise0_.updated_at AS updated_5_6_0_,
    franchise1_.country_id AS country_6_6_1_,
    franchise1_.created_at AS created_2_6_1_,
    franchise1_.name AS name3_6_1_,
    franchise1_.parent_id AS parent_i7_6_1_,
    franchise1_.type AS type4_6_1_,
    franchise1_.updated_at AS updated_5_6_1_,
    country2_.alpha2_code AS alpha2_3_2_,
    country2_.alpha3_code AS alpha3_3_2_,
    country2_.created_at AS created_4_3_2_,
    country2_.name AS name5_3_2_,
    country2_.updated_at AS updated_6_3_2_
FROM
    franchises franchise0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN franchises franchise1_ ON
    franchise0_.parent_id = franchise1_.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN countries country2_ ON
    franchise0_.country_id = country2_.id
WHERE
    franchise0_.id = 3;

SELECT
    franchise0_.id AS id1_6_0_,
    franchise0_.country_id AS country_6_6_0_,
    franchise0_.created_at AS created_2_6_0_,
    franchise0_.name AS name3_6_0_,
    franchise0_.parent_id AS parent_i7_6_0_,
    franchise0_.type AS type4_6_0_,
    franchise0_.updated_at AS updated_5_6_0_
FROM
    franchises franchise0_
WHERE
    franchise0_.id = 135
```

And this is the data that I have in database:

```
|-----|-------------|---------------|-----------|------------|  
|  id | name        | type          | parent_id | country_id |  
|-----|-------------|---------------|-----------|------------|  
| 135 | Franchise A | INTERNATIONAL | NULL      | NULL       |  
|  2  | Franchise B | MASTER        | 135       |  1         |  
|  3  | Franchise C | REGIONAL      |  2        |  1         |  
|  4  | Franchise D | REGIONAL      |  2        |  1         |  
|-----|-------------|---------------|-----------|------------|
```

So by looking at the executed queries I can see (and test) that all data that is needed for me is fetched using first query Franchise+Parent+Country. However then the second query got executed to load parent of the parent which I dont need...

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and why are two queries executed instead of only one?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Franchise parent;
```

to

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Franchise parent;
```

and try.

Comment: I cant do that because I need it to be lazy as I dont need parent every time, just in few use cases.